# Can't download old apps

Tags: iphone, ios-appstore

I recently deleted a bunch of apps on my iPhone 5 so that I would have room for more photos during a trip. I have returned and moved the photos off of the phone, and there is now plenty of space for me to redone load those apps. However, some of these old apps will not download. If I tap the cloud icon, it shows the loading circle for a second and then goes back to the cloud icon. I was only able to redo load two of the apps and I am not sure what is unique about those two.

Comment: Have you tried rebooting your iPhone?  If so, have you tried 'flushing' the cache of the App Store (tap any button in the tab list 10 times and the App Store will refresh)?

Comment: I have tried both of these with no luck. I probably should've mentioned that.

Comment: Have you tried to log out and then back in the AppStore with your AppleID?

Comment: Yes, I've tried that as well unfortunately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well the problem got fixed eventually over time. I was never able to find an actual solution, but eventually more and more of the apps I used to have began to be able to download onto my phone. Not all at once, but eventually I got them all.